# How do I place this directory safely within my folder structure?

Tags: php, directory-structure

In my folder structure, I have a public folder where public users can have access to. However, I have a directory called “proc” that contains php files where ajax requests are sent to. Essentially, this proc directory contains php files that process the data the user sends to them via ajax. I don’t want users to access them directly by typing the uri in the address bar.

Currently, this proc directory sits above the public directory, but I feel I may run into access issues when I deploy it, especially when I modify the .htaccess file to send requests to the public directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could always direct users away from the page if it's not being accessed via AJAX:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    /* AJAX Processing */
} else {
  header('Location: /');
{
```